# How can Comparator be a Functional Interface when it has two abstract methods?

Tags: java, java-8, comparator, functional-interface

In Java 8, the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation is introduced to denote any interface that has exactly one abstract method as a functional interface. One of the reason for its introduction is to indicate the user (programmer), that lambda expression can be used in context of a functional interface.

The `Comparator` interface is annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`. But, two methods are abstract.

```
int compare(T o1, T o2);
```

and

```
boolean equals(Object obj);
```

In the docs of [`FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), it is clearly mentioned as

> Conceptually, a functional interface has exactly one abstract method.

Isn't the `equals` method not considered as abstract here?

Comment: "Conceptually" is probably the key word here, as distinct from "actually."

Comment: `equals` is inherited from `Object`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The docs also state:

> If an interface declares an abstract method overriding one of the public methods of `java.lang.Object`, that also does not count toward the interface's abstract method count since any implementation of the interface will have an implementation from `java.lang.Object` or elsewhere.

And since `equals` is one of those methods, the "abstract method count" of the interface is still 1.

Answer (score 22):

Also from [the `FunctionalInterface` documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html):

> If an interface declares an abstract method **overriding one of the public methods of `java.lang.Object`**, that also **does *not* count** toward the interface's abstract method count since any implementation of the interface will have an implementation from `java.lang.Object` or elsewhere. [emphasis mine]

Since [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) is a public method of `Object`, this statement applies; thus, for `Comparator` only the `compare` method contributes to the abstract method count.

Other notable methods to which this rule applies are [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) and [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--).

Comment: So it's a case of functional interfaces having just one *original* abstract method . . .