# How can Predicate be a Functional Interface if it has more than one abstract method?

Tags: java, lambda, predicate, functional-interface

How can `Predicate` be considered and used as a functional interface when it has several abstract methods?  For example: As well as `test(T t)`; it has:
 `and(Predicate<? super T> other)`, `negate()` and `isEqual(Object targetRef )`.

This question is not a duplicate:  I am already aware of the answers given for [`comparator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616649/how-can-comparator-be-a-functional-interface-when-it-has-two-abstract-methods), but they do not apply here because `negate` and `and` are not inherited from the Object class or any super class.

Comment: Predicate has _one_ abstract method and that is `test`. nothing else is abstract in that interface.

Comment: @Aomine I just explained this question is NOT a duplicate.  I have seen the answers here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616649/how-can-comparator-be-a-functional-interface-when-it-has-two-abstract-methods and here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342499/why-functional-interfaces-in-java-8-have-one-abstract-method

Comment: Those methods are not abstract, they all have bodies. `and` and `negate` are `default` methods, and `isEqual` is `static`.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee  I considered that may be the case but am confused as the Oracle documentation for Predicate appears to offer and and negate as alternative methods to test.  isEqual() comes from Object class so I understand why that method can exist.

Comment: @IqbalHamid [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) does not have a `isEqual()` method.

Comment: You might want to read up on [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).

Comment: OK  studying the Oracle documentation more carefully, I can see that test(T t) is the only abstract method as the others are default as stated by Jorn Vernee.

Comment: Thank you shmosel, I think you are right.  It is gradually making more sense.